# Set HTTP_REFERER to session

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for a way to set `request.env['HTTP_REFERER']` if exists on first user visit to session. Later if user buys something, registers or does any action on the website - grab referer value from the session.

In short, I want to know from where does user came when he makes an important action.

Is it a good way to do this?

If yes, then I will use this code (in layouts/appication.html.erb). But if user has blocked sessions, this code will load on every pageload with no luck:

```
 if request.env['HTTP_REFERER'].present? and !session[:referer].present?
   session[:referer] = request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
 end
```

Comment: `HTTP-REFERER` is not guaranteed to be accurate, or even present. You shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: what else can I use to make this more accurate? Thanks!